# Docker: cannot open port from container to host

Tags: docker, dockerfile, docker-network

I'm using `Docker for Mac`. I have a container that run a server, for example my server is run on port 5000. I have exposed this port on `Dockerfile`

When my container is running, I connect to this container and check and if this server is working or not by running below command and see that it returns data (a bunch of html and javascript)

```
wget -d localhost:5000
```

Notes, I start this container and also publish port outside by command:

```
docker run -d -p 5000:5000 <docker_image_name>
```

But at docker host (is my mac and running El Capitan), I open chrome and go to address `localhost:5000`. It doesn't work. Just a little note, if I go to any arbitrary port such as `localhost:4000` I see error message from chrome such as:

```
This site can’t be reached
localhost refused to connect.
```

But error message for `localhost:5000` is:

```
The localhost page isn’t working
localhost didn’t send any data.
```

So it seems I have configured work "a little" but something wrong. Please tell me how to fix this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Please check the program in container is listening on interface 0.0.0.0.

In container, run command:

```
ss -lntp
```

If it appears like:

```
LISTEN  0   128   127.0.0.1:5000  *:*
```

that means your web app only listen at localhost so container host cannot access to your web app. You should make your server listen at `0.0.0.0` interface by changing your web app build setting.

For example if your server is nodejs app:

```
var app = connect().use(connect.static('public')).listen(5000, "0.0.0.0");
```

If your server is web pack:

```
 "scripts": {
    "dev": "webpack-dev-server --host 0.0.0.0 --port 5000 --progress"
  }
```

Comment: After couple of hours of search, your answer saved me. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I had this problem using Docker for Mac, trying to run an Angular2 app.

I fixed the issue by changing the `start` script in `package.json` to

```json
"scripts": {
    "start": "ng serve --host 0.0.0.0"
}
```

Previously `start` was only `ng serve`.