# Docker: cannot get access to server

Tags: docker, .net-core, microservices

Here is a little of backstory. I implemented a couple of web APIs using microservices architecture. I am trying to make my microservices accessible via HTTPS. The microservices are developed using .net core, so according to Microsoft document, to enforce HTTPS, I need to configure Kestrel. Following is how I did it.

```
.UseKestrel(options =>
            {
                options.Listen(IPAddress.Loopback, 5000);
                options.Listen(IPAddress.Loopback, 5001, listenOptions =>
                {
                    listenOptions.UseHttps("cert.pfx", "pwd");
                });
            })
```

To make it simple, I use kestrel by itself and skip reverse proxy. I will certainly include Nginx as reverse proxy but that is the future work. I tested locally, it worked. Then, I deployed it onto Docker. Here is the docker-compose.override file

```
version: '3.4'

services:
dataservice:
  environment:
    - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
    - ASPNETCORE_URLS=https://+:443;http://+:80
  ports:
    - "5000:80"
    - "5001:443"
```

In dockerfile, port 5000 and 5001 are exposed. I built the project into images, and run it on docker, using `docker run -it --rm -p 5000:80  --name *name* *imagename*`. Docker shows `Now listening on: http://127.0.0.1:5000` and `Now listening on: https://127.0.0.1:5001`. Now the problem is, leave the https part aside, the APIs cannot even accessed by http. The browser just shows `This page isn’t working 127.0.0.1 didn’t send any data. ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE`. I found a similar question from here [Docker: cannot open port from container to host](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40827230/docker-cannot-open-port-from-container-to-host)
, somehow this is about server should listen to 0.0.0.0. Though I am not fully understand the reason, I changed the kestrel  configuration to

```
options.Listen(IPAddress.Any, 5000);
```

built and ran docker images again, and Docker shows `Now listening on: http://0.0.0.0:5000`, still it doesn't work. I also tried to replace the IP with `localhost`, it has no use. I did not use `.UseHttpsRedirection()`, https should have nothing to do with the problem.

Am I missing any configuration or doing anything wrong? It would be really helpful if anyone could shed some light. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should `listen`  on 80 and 443 inside the container, i.e. `options.Listen(IPAddress.Any, 80);` because this docker declaration

```
ports: 
   - "5000:80"
```

means that the local port 80 (the port from your source code) is exported to external port 5000, and not the other way around.

Comment: Thank you, it works. And the HTTPS features is working as well.